# Xamarin Android - where to store images locally

Tags: android, image, bitmap, xamarin

I am writing an app that requires the ability to pull data from a cloud database and store the data locally. I'm using SQLite to store the data when i collect it from the cloud DB, but it's knowing what to do with images.

In the cloud database, I have a URL string pointing to the image. So i now need to be able to grab that image and store it somewhere locally so that i can reference in my code (i need to be able to access it with no internet, so needs to be cached or saved somewhere).

I've done a lot of reading on this but there seems to be some contradiction and dispute in terms of the best way to efficiently store images locally and where. I assume i need to store it as a Bitmap image, but where is considered best for this?

Ideally if the app is deleted, the images should also be deleted. I'm targeting Andorid 4.3 and above only if that makes any difference.

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store them in the applicatoin package path under the files directory: `/data/data/com.your.package.name/files`. This directory is removed when your app is uninstalled from the device.

You can access this directory by using:

```
string filesPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

Comment: Yes,but you cant write/read file there(SpecialFolder.Personal),because access is denied !